# CSS Transition Jumping with Transforms

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate between a full string of text and its abbreviation using CSS transformation transitions (demonstrated in the snippet below).

What I would ideally like to have happen is that letters that are not needed between the full and abbreviated string are scaled horizontally from 0% to 100% (or in the opposite manner), which I have functioning.

However, I would also like the non-transforming letters to compress in position as the transforming letters compress in width, and, while I can implement the former function, I cannot seem to get this one to work.

In short, the code I have written thus far successfully transforms all the letters, but leaves some letters jumping next to each other the moment the transition begins.

```css
#bhead.smaller h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2vh;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 3.5vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#bhead h1 div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 5s linear;
}

#bhead h1 .del {
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

#bhead.smaller h1 .del {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#bhead h1 .undel {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#bhead.smaller h1 .undel {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  width: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15vh;
}
```

```html
<body id="bhead">
  <h1 id="header" class="middle unselectEase"><div>J</div><div class="del">o</div><div>r</div><div class="del">dan&nbsp;</div><div>Ma</div><div class="del"></div><div>nn</div><div class="undel">.com</div>
  </h1>
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('#bhead').className = document.querySelector('#bhead').className == 'smaller' ? '' : 'smaller'">Transform</button>
</body>
```

(You may need to expand the snippet in order for the spacing to work.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! After rediscovering that `width` must transition between two fixed values (which is also difficult with text), I was able to find [this article,](https://coderwall.com/p/mn2a2g/how-to-use-css-transitions-for-height-and-width-from-0px-to-auto) which described how `max-width` can be transitioned instead of `width` to avoid this altogether. The author provides a handy JSFiddle demo as well, but I've fixed the snippet below.

Given, there is a risk in setting the `max-width` attribute, but it's one I'm fine with taking in this specific instance.

```css
#bhead h1 {
  height: 6vh;
  font-size: 6vh;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#bhead.smaller h1 {
  position: fixed;
  top: 2vh;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 3.5vh;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: lowercase;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

#bhead h1 div {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all 5s linear;
  max-width: 20vw;
}

#bhead h1 .del {
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 1;
}

#bhead.smaller h1 .del {
  transform: scaleX(0);
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#bhead h1 .undel {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

#bhead.smaller h1 .undel {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  max-width: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  position: fixed;
  top: 15vh;
}
```

```html
<body id="bhead">
  <h1 id="header" class="middle unselectEase"><div>J</div><div class="del">o</div><div>r</div><div class="del">dan&nbsp;</div><div>Ma</div><div class="del"></div><div>nn</div><div class="undel">.com</div>
  </h1>
  <button onclick="document.querySelector('#bhead').className = document.querySelector('#bhead').className == 'smaller' ? '' : 'smaller'">Transform</button>
</body>
```